# Java generate complex json response

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, graph

I'm trying to create a json response exactly like this

```
{
"clusters": [
    {
        "id": "0-1511866753",
        "nodes": [
            {
                "id": "node12",
                "label": "Symfony",
                "clusterId": "0-1511866753"
            },
            {
                "id": "node2",
                "label": "Php",
                "clusterId": "0-1511866753"
            },
            {
                "id": "node1",
                "label": "Laravel",
                "clusterId": "0-1511866753"
            }
        ]
    }
]}
```

I have achieved the following

```
{
    "clusters": [
        [
            {
                "id": "node1",
                "label": "Laravel",
                "partition": "1",
                "clusterId": "0-7179778"
            },
            {
                "id": "node2",
                "label": "Php",
                "partition": "1",
                "clusterId": "0-7179778"
            },
            {
                "id": "node12",
                "label": "Symfony",
                "partition": "1",
                "clusterId": "0-7179778"
            }
        ]
    ]
}
```

the code I used to build my response:

```java
    Map<Object, List<Map<String, String>>> nodeGroups = nodeList.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(node -> node.get("partition")));

    List<List<Map<String, String>>> list = new ArrayList<>();

    Map<String, List<List<Map<String, String>>>> clusterNodes = new HashMap<>();

    nodeGroups.forEach(
            (key, value) -> {
                int b = (int)((Math.random() * 9000000) + 1000000);
                String uuid = 0 + "-" + b;

                // Append generated clusterId on each node
                value.forEach(nodeValue -> nodeValue.put("clusterId", uuid));
                list.add(value);
            }
    );

    clusterNodes.put("clusters", list);

    return clusterNodes;
```

And the question is what i need to do to achieve the preferred response?

Comment: I would say to not build your own json response, but to Model it in Java and then serialize it to json with something like Jackson. That would be the more java answer I think. (e.g. https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-xml-serialization-and-deserialization)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, model your JSON structure as an object/DTO. It will be converted to what you want. For example, JSON output for this DTO:

```
public class ProductDTO {
    List<ProductBean> data = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Is:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "type": "phone",
            "properties": "color:grön",
            "price": 277.00,
            "store_address": "Blake gränden, Karlskrona"
        }
    ]
}
```

It is using Jackson to convert Object to JSON.